# MP4 video not working on chrome mobile

Tags: html, apache2, html5-video, mp4

I actually have a probleme playing some MP4 video on my phone.
I'm on android 5.0.1, using Chrome 47 with this simple html code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>ssqsq</title>
</head>
<body>
<video controls="" autoplay="" name="media">
<source src=x type="video/mp4">
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

Let say 'x' is a variable where is my source address.
When the address is : http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4 , Chrome read the video without probleme.

But when x is : http://someurl/files/atoms/video/mov_bbb.mp4
(it's the same video, literaly. I download from w3s to upload on this website), my chrome isn't abble to read the video

'someurl' has an .htaccess, but this not seem to be the probleme since the video play normally on chrome(on my desktop) and  even on my androind (using FireFox 43.0)
I have thinking of codec probleme when i was working with other video, but this one (mov_bbb.mp4) does not change between w3s and 'someurl'

I don't know where it could come from.

Not the codec, because video play well on w3s.

Not the server configuration because the video play well on firefox and on desktop...

Advice and help would be thankfull!

Comment: Can you elaborate on the .htaccess? If you are requiring authentication, that could be an issue. Android Chrome may send a different user agent for the media file request.

Comment: Yes, we effectively require authentification.
It's an internal dev website.
But the bug appear egally on the production website, where no auth is required